# Specifying redirect url for Azure Mobile App website login

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-mobile-services

When the App Service has "Action to take when request is not authenticated" set to "Log in with X", any webpage hit gets sent to X for user login. Once the user logs in, the user is redirected to the page where they started.

[image]

For example, when the Social login service is Active Directory B2C, and the user starts from http://example.com/admin/monitor the user is sent to https://login.microsoftonline.com/...?...&state=redir%3D%252Fadmin%252Fmonitor

In this particular instance, I do not want all webpages to require authentication. How can I send a user to .auth/login/aad and specify the redirect_uri so that it comes back to the right page? If I do not specify anything, I end up at

[image]

and the website is only the originating website.

I am looking for something like https://example.com/.auth/login/aad?return_url=blahblah - I sure hope it exists!

Incidentally, there is a "redirect_uri" in aad that goes to /.auth/login/aad/callback. It looks like redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fkamelos-app.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback. This is different than what I am talking about. After it goes to AAD, it goes to the Azure Mobile App and posts state=redir%3D%252Fadmin%252Fmonitor along with the token.

**Update.** I believe I am looking for "post_login_redirect_url"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `post_login_redirect_url` I do not think there's a way to assign it from within a portal.
What you have to do instead is to navigate your users to

```
 /.auth/login/<provider>?post_login_redirect_url=YOUR_URL
```

> Your application can trigger the same redirect itself by navigating
>   the user to the /.auth/login/ endpoint of your site, where
>    is one of aad, facebook, google, microsoftaccount, and
>   twitter

from: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-app-service-authentication-authorization/

If writing additional code is not an option you can [configure an advanced authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication) with AAD (not sure about Google, facebook, etc)

And when you do that you can add post_login_redirect_url to a return url.

Comment: @tofutim, well **post_logout_redirect_uri** should work potentially even though I haven't tested it myself.